# Selecting from Lambda Expression with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have two expressions:

```
  public static Expression<Func<TSource, TReturn>> Merge<TSource, TSource2, TReturn>(
      Expression<Func<TSource, TSource2>> foo1
      Expression<Func<TSource2, TReturn>> foo2)
  {
      // What to do?
  }
```

How can I merge them into a single expression, so the output from the first is used as the input for the second? I am new to these and so far its just been exceptions.

Thanks

Comment: can you add a concrete example that shows what you mean? is this as in `x => x.Name` and `s => s.Length` to get `x => x.Name.Length` ?

Comment: Yeah sorry that's what I meant, for future reference when people come to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on which providers need to use it. Some will be fine with:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TReturn>>
     Merge<TSource, TSource2, TReturn>(
  Expression<Func<TSource, TSource2>> foo1,
  Expression<Func<TSource2, TReturn>> foo2)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TReturn>>(
      Expression.Invoke(foo2, foo1.Body),
      foo1.Parameters);
}
```

However, others (EF) will not. You can also re-write the expression-tree with a visitor to inline the expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TReturn>>
      Merge<TSource, TSource2, TReturn>(
  Expression<Func<TSource, TSource2>> foo1,
  Expression<Func<TSource2, TReturn>> foo2)
{
    var swapped = new SwapVisitor(
        foo2.Parameters.Single(), foo1.Body).Visit(foo2.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TReturn>>(
        swapped, foo1.Parameters);
}

class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

this will work with all providers.

Comment: This indeed worked! Thanks I was extremely close, but I was using foo1, not foo1.Body in my overload of Invoke.

Comment: @Tim see the edit; the inlined version will usually be preferable, since it will work in more places (and can be more direct)

Comment: Also thanks for the extended answer. I am using LINQ-to-Entities so likely will be useful in the future. Edit: Ok thanks!